# C# XUnit Strategy Pattern

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I am having difficulty writing a unit test for the strategy pattern. 
I am writing to write a test that will call the _mathStrategy.Calculate(a, b, Operator.Add) and return a value.
The issue is that I dont know how to instantiate the mathstragegy with the correct values. 
Can someone tell me the correct way to do this.
Thanks

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMathStrategy _mathStrategy;

    public HomeController(IMathStrategy mathStrategy)
    {
        _mathStrategy = mathStrategy;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 5;
        int result = _mathStrategy.Calculate(a, b, Operator.Add);
        return Content(result.ToString());
    }
}

public interface IMathOperator
{
    Operator Operator { get; }

    int Calculate(int a, int b);
}

public interface IMathStrategy
{
    int Calculate(int a, int b, Operator op);
}

public class MathStrategy : IMathStrategy
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IMathOperator> _operators;

    public MathStrategy(IEnumerable<IMathOperator> operators)
    {
        _operators = operators;
    }

    public int Calculate(int a, int b, Operator op)
    {
        return _operators.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Operator == op)?.Calculate(a, b) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(op));
    }
}

public enum Operator
{
    Add,
    Substract,
    Multiple,
    Divide
}
```

My attempt at a test

```
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    public IMathStrategy MathStrategy;
    public HomeControllerTest()
    {
        MathStrategy = new mathStrategy(new List<IMathOperator>());
    }
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
       var s = MathStrategy.Calculate(1, 2, Operator.Add);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why stops you from passing the IEnumerable? Also, what is your goal? Do you want to mock the Strategy? Do you want to test the strategy itself?

Comment: I am trying to write a unit test that return the values called from the MathStrategy .I dont want to mock it. I want to actually call it

Comment: Who prevents you to write something like `MathStrategy = new MathStrategy(new List<IMathOperator>(){ op1,op2,.. });`? Using actual implementations of `IMathOperator`

Comment: I having an issue implementing the IMathOperator correctly

Comment: Correct implementation of `IMathOperator` has nothing related to xunit test patterns. Your question and actual problem doesn't match each other

Answer (score 1):

You can do many things here.

If you wish to test the code of the controller calling the `IMathStrategy` and returning the correct response, you can simply mock the IMathStrategy. Either create your own class: `MockMathStrategy : IMathStrategy` which will return whatever you define it to, or you can use the `Moq` library.

I do not see any reason why you can't use the `IEnumerable<IMathOperator>` there, though. You can still use the concrete implementation.

To take it a step further, you can test the MathStrategy itself, that it calls the correct operator, and then each operator separately.

EDIT: To clear things up about IMathOperator, a sample implementation could be:

```
public class AddOperator : IMathOperator
{
    public Operator Operator => Operator.Add;

    public int Calculate(int a, int b) 
    {
       return a + b;
    }
}
```

You can use these little classes in your `MathStrategy` constructor now and test the concrete implementation.

To test the implementation of each operator, you can do this quite easily now, since they do not require any other dependency

Comment: The problem i dont know what to call the new MathStrategy correctly.
MathStrategy = new MathStrategy(new List<IMathOperator>() { Operator.Add });
What do i pass in here {"""""""}.
The  Operator Operator { get; }   int Calculate(int a, int b); is used.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a sample implementation of the AddOperator

Comment: Sorry are you saying that i should inject each operation into the MathStrategy constructor cause i am trying to avoid having to do that. Sorry i am new to this unit testing

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to ensure your `MathStrategy` implementation is calling the `IMathOperator`, but not to actually test your `IMathOperator`, then you need to mock your `IMathOperator`, like this:

```
// arrange
var mock = new Moq<IMathOperator>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Operator).Returns(Operator.Add);

var strategy = new MathStrategy(new[] { mock .Value });

// act
strategy.Add(0, 0, Operator.Add);

// assert the strategy called the mock add operator
mock.Verify(foo => foo.Calculate(0, 0));
```

Comment: My goal is to test IMathOperator. I dont want to use Moq. I would like to call the actionMethod and go through the flow of code and return the correct value at the end of it.

Comment: I also dont really see the point of mocking very thing and then calling mock.verify. I am new to unit testing.

Comment: There are two ways to test the `strategy.Calculate()` method. You can verify the result, i.e., it returns the correct value, or you can verify the behavior, i.e. that it calls the correct operators. Often when you're testing an object that orchestrates other objects you want to test the behavior.